# Dplyr mutate_if numeric columns but exclude a column or condition on numeric value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a very simple need on a data frame with large number of numeric columns. I want to round down all numeric values to one decimal max, but exclude one specific column by name or position or whatever from this rounding.

For example, in this case, I don't want `drat` column to be rounded down, let us say.

```
mtcars %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 1)
```

How can I do this, without having enumerate all columns? BTW - my data has non-numeric columns too, and so `mutate_if` sounds right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use mutate/across as shown.  `drat` can be replaced with `5` if desired since `drat` is the fifth column.  If we had `ix <- "drat"` or `ix <- 5` then replace `drat` with `all_of(ix)` .

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric) & !drat, ~ round(.x, 1)))
```

giving

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat  wt qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.6 16.5  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.9 17.0  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.3 18.6  1  1    4    1
...snip...
```